# How to display notes Link pop up on application homepage with conditiions

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, batch, schedulebatch

I needs to display an alert pop up condition, i can use LWC modal to display the pop up but  I needs to display it with below conditions. How we can I achieve it ? If we use any schedule or batch apex, is it possible to show the pop with below conditions ?

**Alert pop up Condition :**

**​2 weeks, day after release**

**Appear max 3 times, 3 days in between.**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know, salesforce released the new feature in-app guidance which I am exactly looking for. Below is the link.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customhelp_lexguid.htm&type=5